# app_offline not being respected?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I'm doing some tests with deploying an application using the app_offline.htm functionality in asp.net. I've found that if I have a working application, and I put an app_offline.htm file in the root, and then rename the \bin folder, my app_offline.htm file does not get displayed. If I rename the bin folder back to "bin", my app_offline.htm file gets displayed as expected. I had assumed/thought that the presence of app_offline would supersede anything else that happens...am I mistaken? This is on Windows 7/IIS 7.5.

Comment: It was a test...as part of the deployment I delete all the files in the folder *except* the app_offline.htm. I wanted to see what was causing the issue.

Comment: After you rename your "bin" directory, what happens? Do you get a 404 error?

Comment: @Andy Oh man, that was a long time ago, and I'm not at that job anymore. I think I got some other IIS7.5 error when that happened.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your app is being restarted/recompiled because you're messing with the bin folder. I found this blog post helpful: http://blog.kurtschindler.net/more-app_offline-htm-woes/. I also tried making app_offline.htm the first default document for the site and found that to eliminate any YSOD recompile issues.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say that a change to your /bin (in this case, the change being its deleted) is triggering IIS to recycle your app.  app_offline.htm stops that from happening for content changes and deletions, but not /bin directory deletions.  I'd imagine you'd see similar behavior if you renamed the directory instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .net runtime version for the app pool.  app_offline.htm is only supported in 2.0 and above.  If the app pool is running .net 1.1, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue in IIS 8 (win Server2008 r2) and was unable to find a solution as all the suggested fixes had no impact.  What I discovered is that if the app_offline file size is greater then 1200kB it won't work.

A recent branding change to my app_offline file resulting in additional base64 images and fonts which pushed the file over this limit and result in it no longer working, removing the old base64 images that were commented out resulted in a smaller file size and it started to work.

I came across the 1200kB by trial and error so the actual cut off value might be slightly above or below.